# How to show sub-menu on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to show the `sub-menu` item list on the hover main menu item. Here is the code I tried with the CSS code below but failed, Any help would be much appreciated.

CSS:

```css
summary.header__menu-item.list-menu__item.link:hover u.header__inline-menu details[open] > .header__submenu,
summary.header__menu-item.list-menu__item.link:focus .header__inline-menu details[open]>.header__submenu {
    display: block;
}
```

HTML Structure here:

```html
<nav class="header__inline-menu">
    <ul class="list-menu list-menu--inline" role="list">
        <li>
            <a href="/" class="header__menu-item header__menu-item list-menu__item link link--text focus-inset">
                <span>Home</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <details-disclosure>
                <details id="Details-HeaderMenu-2">
                    <summary class="header__menu-item list-menu__item link focus-inset" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="HeaderMenu-MenuList-2">
                        <span><a style="text-decoration:none;" href="/pages/meal-kits">Meal Kits</a></span>
        
                        <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" role="presentation" class="icon icon-caret" viewBox="0 0 10 6">
                            <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M9.354.646a.5.5 0 00-.708 0L5 4.293 1.354.646a.5.5 0 00-.708.708l4 4a.5.5 0 00.708 0l4-4a.5.5 0 000-.708z" fill="currentColor"></path>
                        </svg>
                    </summary>
                    <ul id="HeaderMenu-MenuList-2" class="header__submenu list-menu list-menu--disclosure caption-large motion-reduce" role="list" tabindex="-1">
                        <li>
                            <a href="/collections/jamaica" class="header__menu-item list-menu__item link link--text focus-inset caption-large">Jamaica</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/collections/guyana" class="header__menu-item list-menu__item link link--text focus-inset caption-large">Guyana</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/collections/trinidad" class="header__menu-item list-menu__item link link--text focus-inset caption-large">Trinidad &amp; Tobago</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </details>
            </details-disclosure>
        </li>
    </ul>       
</nav>
```

Comment: Can you explain how is it not working? Also, can you convert your code into a snippet so we can reproduce the behavior?

Comment: @LajosArpad Thanks for your response, actually didn't get any impact with the CSS code I wrote here.

Comment: Now I understand the problem statement.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible with CSS. You can only toggle a `details` content by click on its child `summary` or via JavaScript. So in your case, you should modify your markup and use CSS like this

```css
.has-submenu {
    position: relative;
}
.header__submenu{
   display: none;
   position: absolute;
}
.has-submenu:hover a + .header__submenu {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav class="header__inline-menu">
    <ul class="list-menu list-menu--inline" role="list">
        <li>
            <a href="/" class="header__menu-item header__menu-item list-menu__item link link--text focus-inset">
                <span>Home</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="has-submenu">
            <a style="text-decoration:none;" href="/pages/meal-kits">
                Meal Kits
                <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" role="presentation" class="icon icon-caret" viewBox="0 0 10 6" width="15">
                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M9.354.646a.5.5 0 00-.708 0L5 4.293 1.354.646a.5.5 0 00-.708.708l4 4a.5.5 0 00.708 0l4-4a.5.5 0 000-.708z" fill="currentColor"></path>
                </svg>
            </a>
            <ul class="header__submenu list-menu list-menu--disclosure caption-large motion-reduce">
                <li>
                    <a href="/collections/jamaica" class="header__menu-item list-menu__item link link--text focus-inset caption-large">Jamaica</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/collections/guyana" class="header__menu-item list-menu__item link link--text focus-inset caption-large">Guyana</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/collections/trinidad" class="header__menu-item list-menu__item link link--text focus-inset caption-large">Trinidad &amp; Tobago</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>       
</nav>
```

Comment: I also understood that this cannot be done with CSS. And it is not possible to change the markup. If you help me with how to do it with JavaScript, it is very useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can define it like this as far as I'm guessing. can't get a full picture from that code. css isn't properly working.

```
.header__submenu{
   display: none;
}
.header__menu-item:hover .header__submenu{
   display; block;
}
```